# Which `ls` program is used when running dired over tramp?

Tags: dired, tramp

How does dired determine which `ls` program to use when running over tramp? I couldn't find it anywhere in the document. If it is `insert-directory-program`, what would it do if the path doesn't exist on the remote host?

Comment: Have you tested setting `insert-directory-program` to a value which doesn't exist on the remote host?

Comment: @phils I tested, doesn't seem to have any effects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tramp does not use `insert-directory-program`. It has its own mechanism to detect a proper `ls` program.

Dired is not involved at all. It calls `insert-directory`, and let the local implementation, or the Tramp implementation run.